# Display Configurable Product from Simple/Virtual Product : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute

Here, I'm Display Custom Product Collection Filter By **Type** => **'virtual'**
I need Configurable Product With Selection of Attribute On Click Of That relavant Configurable Product Is Open With Selection of Particular Selected Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> I Found the Answer... Here is My Answer

`vendor\module_name\etc\events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view">
        <observer name="config_product_display" instance="vendor\module_name\Observer\Test" />
    </event>
</config>
```

`vendor\module_name\Observer\Test.php`

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module_name\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Test implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $registry;
    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_productTypeConfigurable;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $productTypeConfigurable,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->_productTypeConfigurable = $productTypeConfigurable;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request */
        $request = $observer->getEvent()
            ->getRequest();
        $simpleProductId = $request->getParam('id'); 
        //$this->registry->registry('virtualId');
        if (!$simpleProductId) {
            return;
        }
        $simpleProduct = $this->_productRepository->getById($simpleProductId, false, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        /*if (!$simpleProduct || $simpleProduct->getTypeId() != \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE) {
            return;
        }*/

        $configProductId = $this->_productTypeConfigurable->getParentIdsByChild($simpleProductId);
        if (isset($configProductId[0])) {
            $configProduct = $this->_productRepository->getById($configProductId[0], false, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            $configType = $configProduct->getTypeInstance();
            $attributes = $configType->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($configProduct);
            $options = [];
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                $id = $attribute['attribute_id'];
                $value = $simpleProduct->getData($attribute['attribute_code']);
                $options[$id] = $value;
            }
            $options = http_build_query($options);
            $hash = $options ? '#' . $options : '';
            $configProductUrl = $configProduct->getUrlModel()
                ->getUrl($configProduct) . $hash;
            $this->_redirect->setRedirect($configProductUrl, 301);
        }
    }
}
```